# Plugin to make Sabredav 2.1.3 work with PCRE 7.8

Tags: pcre, backwards-compatibility, owncloud, sabredav

I installed own cloud but it requires a higher version than PCRE 7.8 due to sabredav 2.1.3

Does anyone one know of a plugin that I can install to make sabredav backward compatible? Unfortunately my host won't allow me to update it. Tried googling but I couldn't find anything.